# Java program not terminating in minority of cases

Tags: java, string

I was set a java assignment to find the shortest superstring of 20 randomly assigned strings of length 15. Using the greedy algorithm I wrote the following solution. The section of the code that i have written is between

```
// DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING ABOVE THIS LINE
```

And

```
// DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE
```

.

```
// find the shortest string which contains 

import java.util.*;
public class SuperString3 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        int fail=0, evid=-1; // failure flag + evidence
        float REF=100; // reference point
        float Quotient=100;
        String Solution=""; // initialisation of the solution
        String[] S = new String[20];
        String[] R = new String[100]; // random sequence
        int[] T = new int[100]; // cover test
        Random rnumb = new Random();
        int r=0, cover=0;

        // generate a random sequence R of length 100
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            if (rnumb.nextInt(1000)>850) {R[i]="1";} else {R[i]="0";}
        }

        for (;cover==0;){
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                if ((i<15)||(i>84)) {T[i]=1;} else {T[i]=0;}
            }
            cover=1; 

        // draw randomly 20 strings (of length 15 each) from R[], make sure R[] is covered

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                S[i]="";
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                if (i==0) {
                    for(int j=0; j<15; j++){
                        S[i]=S[i]+R[j];
                    }
                }

                if (i==1) {
                    for(int j=0; j<15; j++){
                        S[i]=S[i]+R[85+j];
                    }
                }

                if (i>1) {
                    r= rnumb.nextInt(85);
                    for(int j=0; j<15; j++){
                        S[i]=S[i]+R[r+j]; T[r+j]=1;
                    }
                }
            }

        // check whether we have a proper coverage

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                if (T[i]==0) {cover=0;}
            }

        if (cover==0) {System.out.println("Invalid cover");} else {System.out.println("Valid cover");}

        } // end of the loop generating good cover

        // reset the random sequence

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            R[i]="0";
        }

        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        // DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING ABOVE THIS LINE
        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        // Print the input array
        System.out.println("Inputs: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.println("S[" + i + "] : " + S[i]);
        }


        // Turns the input array into a HashSet
        HashSet<String> Elements = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < S.length; i++) {
            String Value = S[i];
            Elements.add(Value);
        }

        // Initialise variables
        int TotalStrings = Elements.size();
        String[] Match = new String[TotalStrings];
        int i = 0;

        // Loop to find the two strings that can be concatenated
        for(String SuperString : Elements) {
            Set<String> Temp = new HashSet<String>(Elements);
            String MaxSuperString = SuperString;
            while(Temp.size() > 1) {
                String subString = "";
                String nextMaxSuperString = MaxSuperString;
                for(String nextString : Temp) {
                    if(!nextString.equals(nextMaxSuperString)) {
                        String result = MaxSuperString;
                        int endIndex = nextString.length() - 1;
                        while(endIndex > 0 && !MaxSuperString.endsWith(nextString.substring(0, endIndex)))  {
                             endIndex--;
                            }

                        if(endIndex > 0) {
                            result += nextString.substring(endIndex);
                        }

                        else {
                            result += nextString;
                         }

                        String superTemp = result; 
                        if (nextMaxSuperString.equals(MaxSuperString) || nextMaxSuperString.length() > superTemp.length()) {
                            nextMaxSuperString = superTemp;
                            subString = nextString;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Replace the two strings with the concatenated string
                Temp.remove(MaxSuperString);
                Temp.remove(subString);
                MaxSuperString = nextMaxSuperString;
                Temp.add(MaxSuperString);
            }

            Match[i] = MaxSuperString;
            i++;
        }

        // Check is the answer is the best answer
        String bestAns = Match[0];
        for(i = 1; i < Match.length; i++) {
            if(bestAns.length() > Match[i].length()) {
                bestAns = Match[i];
            }
        }

        // Print the final string
        System.out.println("Shortest Common SuperString = " + bestAns);

        Solution=bestAns;

        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        // DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE
        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!       

        // computes how many string are not included

        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if (!Solution.contains(S[i])) {fail++;evid=i;}
        }

        // Calculation of the quality quotient (wrt the reference REF)

        Quotient=((float)Solution.length())/REF;

        if (fail>0) {System.out.println(" This is not a superstring, string S["+evid+"] is not included, #fails= "+fail);} 
            else {System.out.println(" Well done! Your quality quotient= "+Quotient);}


   }

}
```

In the majority of cases it terminates:

[image]

On some occasions the program does not terminates how i would like it to:

[image]

Not fully sure what is going wrong and why it does not terminate in some occasions?

Comment: `System.out.println("Invalid cover");` <- **You** wrote that code (at least you say so). You added code to print "Invalid cover" or "Valid cover". So why are you asking us what the point of that is? Or was that piece of code supplied by your tutor/teacher? In that case you should probably ask him about its meaning.

Comment: Apologies i did not write that section of the code. I wrote the section between the Do not change above and bellow comments. I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop goes into infinite loop when your "SuperString" variable equals to all zero.("000000000000000")

There is a logical error with your code I think.

```
// Loop to find the two strings that can be concatenated
for(String SuperString : Elements) {
    Set<String> Temp = new HashSet<String>(Elements);
    String MaxSuperString = SuperString;
    while(Temp.size() > 1) {
```